# Изменить высоту radiobutton в C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть `RadioButton` на форме. его ширина (`Width`) привязана к ширине форме

```
radiobutton.Width = this.Width - 50;
```

`RadioButton` заполняется текстом

```
rb[i] = new RadioButton();
rb[i].Text = listOfAnswers[numOfBut][i].answer;
```

Если текст не помещается, он просто сжирается. Как увеличивать высоту (`Height`) по мере переноса текста на новую строку?

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: да, Windows Form

Answer (score 2):

Используйте свойство `AutoSize`. Для того чтобы `AutoSize` работал только по высоте, установите ширину в свойствах `MaximumSize.Width` и `MinimumSize.Width` - это не позволит ширине меняться автоматически, ну привязку к ширине формы делайте через них.

```
AutoSize = true;
radioButton1.MaximumSize = new Size(Width / 2, 0);
radioButton1.MinimumSize = new Size(Width / 2, 0);
```

Более подробно `AutoSize` и некоторые его особенности в сочетании с другими свойствами можно почитать [**тут**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/550619/198316)