# scrollbar на Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Помогите, пожалуйста, как реализовать scrollbar на winforms c#? Я добавила элемент на форму, но что нужно сделать, чтобы он двигался?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/550616/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy дубликат?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, нет. Там в самом вопросе (в видео) есть ответ на этот, но это явно не дубликат.

Comment: Ну и кому вопрос с ответом в одно имя свойства кажется слишком общим? о_О

Answer (score 3):

Можно установить в true свойство Autoscroll у формы. Тогда при необходимости будет отображаться скролбар.