# C# WinForms. Бесконечный длинны компонент

Tags: c#, controls

**Опишу идею:**
Допустим есть RichTextBox. Туда можно писать сколько угодно строк, и по мере роста строк, будет расти ScrollBar компонента.

Есть ли какой-нибудь аналог, чтобы по такому принципу можно было построить, что-то вроде "Новостной ленты" т.е выводить не текст, а скажем другие компоненты (к примеру: кнопка для лайка + картинка)

Comment: Для WinForms смотрите `FlowLayoutPanel`, можете размещать все что вам нужно. Ну и этот ответ тоже, чтобы не мучиться с особенностями реализации http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/550619/198316

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть другой компонент уже предназначен для того что ты хочешь называется ListBox. В нем можно настроить сразу и кнопки и картинки и все что пожелаешь:)

Данный компонент есть как в WF так же и в WPF

[ListBox Tutorial](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/UI_WPF/level6/6_17.php)