# WinForms: GroupBox со свойствами DockStyle.Left, AutoSize=true уменьшается в размерах игнорируя минимальную ширину содержащихся компонентов

Tags: c#, winforms

Существует очередь компонентов которая должна содержаться на форме. На очередь компонентов повлиять нельзя. Каждый из компонентов, в свою очередь, может так-же являться контейнером со своими контролами и все они должны быть корректно отрисованы.

**Для примера**

Предположим что на форме у нас существует один `GroupBox`, а в `GroupBox` последовательно помещены компоненты `Panel(){Dock=DockStyle.Top}`, `Splitter(){Dock=DockStyle.Top}`, `new Panel(){Dock=DockStyle.Top}`, `new Panel(){Dock=DockStyle.Fill}`.

Для всех `Panel` устанавливаем свойства `MinimumSize = new Size(200, 40)`

Получаем вот такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для `GroupBox` устанавливаем свойства `MinimumSize = new Size(30, 30)`, `AutoSize = true`, `Dock = DockStyle.Left`

Наблюдаем картину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`GroupBox` проигнорировал минимальную ширину компонентов `Panel` и схлопнулся до собственного минимального размера.

**Вопросы:**

1) Почему так происходит?

2) Как добиться того что-бы GroupBox не игнорировал минимальную ширину компонента TextBox в такой ситуации и при этом оставить работоспособный `Splitter` между `Panel`?

*p.s. По условию необходимо формировать ряд групп (между которыми так-же может быть сплиттер) которые будут последовательно находиться по горизонтали. Поля в группе должны быть расположены последовательно по вертикали.*

**Буду рад любым подсказкам**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

К сожалению, вы нашли еще одну "особенность" форм. Пожалуй WinForms - тот редкий случай, где наличие множественного наследования в C# могло бы, чисто теоретически, помочь избежать некоторого количества граблей. [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/550616/198316) еще один замечательный пример "особенностей" контейнеров WinForms, там же есть линк на исходники.

Теперь по делу. Просто настройками это можно исправить, но не слишком удобно, особенно если не хочется руками позиционировать контролы. Если это не критично. см соседний ответ.

Дело в том, что когда вы привязываете контрол через свойство `Dock`, то дочерний котрол подгоняет свои размеры под родительский, но строго после того, как родительский контрол изменил свои размеры. Иными словами, минимальный размер вашего `TextBox`, проверяется после того, как `GroupBox` схлопнулся до своего минимального размера. Вообще, там довольно мудреная связь между свойствами, отвечающими за размеры, посмотрите ответ по ссылке выше, что бы не дублировать.

Чтобы получить:

> По условию необходимо формировать группы полей которые будут последовательно находиться по горизонтали. Поля в группе должны быть расположены последовательно по вертикали.

и при этом иметь нормальную картинку обойдя все "особенности", необходимо:

1. За основу возьмем `Panel`, можно и форму, разница, в данном случае, не велика. Так как контент динамический, то существует ненулевая вероятность. что он не поместится на панели целиком, поэтому включаем у панели `AutoScroll = true`.
2. Добавляем на `Panel` `FlowLayoutPanel`, и задаем свойство `Location = 0,0`. **Важно: свойство Dock = None, иначе не будет работать как задумано.** `AutoSize = true`, `AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink`, `WrapContents = false`, `FlowDirection = LeftRight`.
3. На `FlowLayoutPanel` добавляем `GroupBox`-ы, количество по желанию, со свойствами `AutoSize = true`, `AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink`, `Dock = None`.
4. В `GroupBox` добавляем `FlowLayoutPanel` со свойствами `AutoSize = true`, `AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink`, `WrapContents = false`, `Dock = Fill`, `FlowDirection = TopDown`.
5. На `FlowLayoutPanel` `GroupBox`-а кидаем через один `Label`-ы (подписи к полям) и `TextBox`-ы, тех размеров, которые нужны для отображения данных.

В результате, имеем размещение элементов сверху вниз внутри `GroupBox` и `GroupBox`-ы, размещенные слева направо. Все элементы видны в полный размер. Если не уместились, появятся нужные скролы и все можно будет увидеть. Единственный недостаток - при вертикальном скроле, будут прокручиваться все элементы сразу, что не очень красиво. Но я пока не придумал как красиво сделать индивидуальный вертикальный скрол у каждого `GroupBox`.

---

**Альтернативное решение со сплиттером**

Особенность работы со сплиттером, заключается в том, что хотя бы один элемент из двух, между которыми находится сплиттер, не должен иметь значений свойств `AutoSize = true` и `Dock = DockStyle.Fill`. Если у обоих элементов эти свойства имеют такие значения, то сплиттер попросту не работает.

В таком случае решением будет следующая компоновка контрола:

1. За основу возьмем `Panel(0)`.
2. На `Panel(0)` добавляем `GroupBox` со свойством `AutoSize = false`. Если этот `GroupBox` последний - `Dock = Fill`, иначе - `Dock = Left`.

   2.1. В `GroupBox` добавляем `Panel(1)` со свойствами `AutoSize = false`, `AutoScroll = true`. Если в этом `GroupBox` еще требуются сплиттеры `Dock = Up`, иначе `Dock = Fill` и идем в пункт 2.3.

   2.2. В `GroupBox` добавляем `Splitter` со свойством `Dock = Up`.

   2.3. На `Panel(1)` добавляем через один `Label`-ы (подписи к полям) и `TextBox`-ы, со свойствами `AutoSize = false`, `Dock = Up`.
3. Если `GroupBox` единственный - закончили, иначе - на `Panel(0)` добавляем `Splitter` со свойством `Dock = Left` и возвращаемся в пункт 2.

Все сплиттеры работают, и у элементов групбоксов работает вертикальный скролл, но при этом не возможно ни какими средствами задействовать общий вертикальный скрол колонок и общий горизонтальный скрол. Групповой скрол может появиться, если у последних элементов заменить `Dock = Fill` на `Dock = Up`, но при этом перестают работать сплиттеры. Начальную ширину групбоксов нужно вычислять заранее, например как отношение ширины панели к количеству групбоксов.

Больше действующих вариантов без наследования и переопределения поведения контролов по-умолчанию, найти не удалось. Возможно что-то могут предложить платные библиотеки компонентов, вроде SyncFusion и DevExpress, но больно уж специфическая задача, так что я бы на это не рассчитывал особо.

Comment: Отличный ответ! Спасибо! Но, к сожалению этот ответ не подойдёт т.к. в нем нельзя использовать Splitter (Или можно, возможно вы мне расскажете как?) Я реализовал что-то похожее на TableLayoutPanel, однако в ней Splitter так-же не имеет смысла :(

Comment: Сори, ошибся. Я имел ввиду Splitter

Comment: @V.Dmitriy опишите это в вопросе, посмотрим, скорее всего изменения будут незначительными, но нужно понимать что менять

Comment: @V.Dmitriy сплитер актуален, когда размер контейнера фиксирован, и то, больше двух сплитеров заставить нормально работать практически не реально, матрешкой разве что, да то не так чтобы это давало очень хорошие результаты

Comment: откорректировал вопрос. Можно было спроектировать интерфейс и без использования сплиттера. Но, к сожалению, Splitter присутствует в т.з.

Comment: В течении часа еще раз откорректирую вопрос что-бы более точно передать задачу

Comment: Откорректировал

Comment: @V.Dmitriy т.е. сплитер отделяет шапку групбокса от полей, он там единственный? Если да, то можно попробовать и это побороть. Сплитеры между каждой парой полей работать будут странно

Comment: Нет. Сплиттер может располагаться где угодно, их может быть несколько

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57243/discussion-between-rdorn-and-v-dmitriy).

Comment: Да, я примерно так и решил проблему. Ещё есть вариант размещать содержимое с помощью TableLayoutPanel и написать собственный сплиттер для TableLayoutPanel. Спасибо вам!

Answer (score 1):

Помогает следующее:

```
TextBox.Dock = DockStyle.None;
```

Остальные свойства те же самые.

Comment: Если я правильно понял автора, смысл как раз в том что бы `Dock` был `Left`, а не что то другое.. Возможно я ошибаюсь, надеюсь автор уточнить.

Comment: Здесь checkbox.Minimumsize меньше длины textbox,MinimumSize. А за счет того, что элемент не закреплен (DockStyle.None) checkbox.AutoSize подгонит чекбокс под размер самого большого текстбокса. При этом, если в конструкторе они выровнены по левому краю, то и при запуске выравнивание такое же сохранится, что как раз и нужно автору.

Comment: @AntonKomyshan, вообще иметь Dock.Top для текстбокс не принципиально. Но важно последовательно поместить все компоненты по вертикали. У второго ответа есть обсуждение в чате. Для наглядности изменил TextBox на Panel