# Почему при уменьшении формы элементы обрезаются при переносе на следующую строку Winforms C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма с двумя панельками (у каждой есть типа заголовок (синий) и контент (розовый)).

[image]

В каждой панельке есть желтые квадраты. Сейчас они расположены нормально, но если уменьшить форму, не влезающие перенесуться на следующую строку. Но размер розовой области почему-то не увеличивается и квадраты обрезаются.

[image]

Почему? И как сделать так, чтобы все работало и квадраты переносились не обрезаясь?

Вот код:

```
        public readonly Label Label;
        public readonly FlowLayoutPanel LayoutPanel;
        public readonly Panel Panel;

        public Field(string name, IEnumerable<IElement> elements)
        {
            var builtElements = elements
                .Select(e => e.Build(150))
                .ToList();
            Panel = new Panel
            {
                //Height = 700,
                BackColor = Color.Brown,
                Dock = DockStyle.Top,
                Margin = new Padding(20),
                AutoSize = true,
                AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink,
            };
            Label = new Label
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Top,
                Size = new Size(100, 50),
                BackColor = Globals.MenuElement,
                Font = Globals.HeaderBarFont,
                ForeColor = Globals.FontLight,
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
            };
            LayoutPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Top,
                BackColor = Color.Magenta,
                Padding = new Padding(10),
                Margin = new Padding(20),
                AutoSize = true,
                AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink,
                WrapContents = true
            };
            foreach (var e in builtElements) 
                LayoutPanel.Controls.Add(e);

            Panel.Controls.Add(LayoutPanel);
            Panel.Controls.Add(Label);
        }
```

Comment: Причина в том, что пересчет размера для использования FlowLayoutPanel.WrapContents происходит после всех пересчетов для Dock.Top по всем вложенным контролам. Т.е. на момент докинга у FLP учитывается размер по вертикали в одну строку, т.к. у нее выставлен AutoSize, а это значит, что контент по любому уместится. Когда же все операции докинга завершены, включается опция WrapContents, размер меняется, но об этом уже не сообщается родительскому контейнеру и вы видите то, что видите. У меня нет готового совета, надо экспериментировать с компоновкой, возможно отказ от Dock.Top в пользу той же FLP

Comment: Ну и посмотрите еще про нюансы контейнеров WinForms [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/653952/198316) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/550619/198316), будет полезно

Comment: Не, был неправ, у FlowLayoutPanel все еще хуже с сочетанием Dock + Autosize + WrapContents, в общем это косяк самой FlowLayoutPanel и как красиво его обойти с ходу не могу придумать.