# Как можно сделать отображение формы списком

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть вот такая Widows форма[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ней отображаются данные о пользователе, но так не удобно смотреть данные о всех пользователях, приходится открывать каждого пользователя отдельно

Есть ли способ отображать данные вот так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть сколько пользователей в списке столько и карточек, или хотя бы по 50-100 штук

Comment: использовать wpf, либо в коде генерировать элементы(например в панель засунуть одну форму) а потом размножить с определением параметрами.

Comment: Можно по подробнее

Comment: Существует элемент [DataRepeater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.datarepeater.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) в библиотеке [VisualBasic Power Packs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25169). Несмотря на название, его можно использовать и в C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Весь контент, который сейчас лежит на форме, переписываем в `UserControl`. В отдельных случаях для этого достаточно заменить наследование:
   `UserInfo : Form` => `UserInfo : UserControl`.
2. Добавляем новую пустую форму. У формы включаем `AutoScroll`.
3. На форму добавляем `FlowLayoutPanel` с включенным `AutoSize`, `Location = 0; 0` и `ScrollDirection = TopDown`. Можно включить свойства `Dock = Fill` и `AutoScroll = true` у самой FLP (у формы в таком случае `AutoScroll = false`), но если собираетесь играть с `Margin` и `Padding`, то в нагрузку добавится неприятный эффект. Про нюансы FLP читать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/550619/198316). Если `Margin` и `Padding` не требуются, смело включайте, будет меньше проблем с позиционированием скрола.
4. После того как получили список пользователей, для каждого создаете и заполняете `UserInfo`, который у нас теперь `UserControl`, и добавляете его на FLP. Например `flp.Controls.Add(new UserInfo(UserData));`, естественно предварительно добавив соответствующий конструктор в `UserInfo`.

---

При длинных списках может потребоваться виртуализация отображения. Надо помнить, что даже самый простейщий `Label` является полноценным окном с точки зрения WinAPI, со всеми накладными расходами, в виде хендлов и прочих неуправляемых ресурсов, и если держать их все в памяти постоянно, может возникнуть проблема с производительностью. Впрочем про виртуализацию лучше отдельным вопросом, если она понадобится.