# C# Winforms. Как переключить форму заменив её без анимации всплывания окна

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Переключаю одну форму на другую через frm.Show(); (чтобы показать нужную форму) и Hide(); (чтобы спрятать текущую), но при этом проигрывается анимация всплывания окна, к тому же позиция нового окна не та. Как мне осуществить переход между формами так, чтобы пользователю казалось то, что меняется все содержимое формы, а не открывается новая?

Comment: Менять содержимое внутри формы. Создайте юзерконтролы с необходимыми элементами и меняйте их местами, когда требуется. Ну либо почитайте что-то про MDI формы. В WPF и более свежих UI движках такое делается за считанные минуты.

Comment: Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/574140/198316) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/893182/198316) посмотрите и используйте `UserControl` вместо `Form`. Ответ можете сами скомпилировать из этих двух ответов, переписывать еще раз, честно говоря лениво, сорри

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.panel?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). Сделайте главную форму с панелью, а уже на панели отображайте ваши формы. Удобно тем, что не нужно менять код форм, и можно будет по-прежнему отображать форму как всплывающее окно при необходимости.

Пример метода главной формы приложения для открытия форм на панели главной формы с примером хэндлера команды меню для открытия формы:

```
public Form OpenInlineForm<T>() where T : Form, new() {
    try {
        var form = new T() {
            Dock = DockStyle.None, TopLevel = false, TopMost = true,
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None, StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent
        };
        foreach (Form frm in aPanel.Controls) frm.Close();
        aPanel.Controls.Clear(); aPanel.Controls.Add(form);
        form.Show(); return form;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { return null; }
}
...
void aToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => OpenInlineForm<MyFormClass>();
```

Зачем нужна панель? Она нужна для лучшего позиционирования, если на форме есть другие элементы управления (а на главной форме чаще всего присутствуют строка меню и строка статуса).

Comment: Свойство `Form.TopLevel`, использование которого казалось бы очевидно, если знаешь что оно есть и помнишь об этом. Но даже в этом случае промежуточная панель не обязательна =)

Comment: @rdorn Я бы не сказал, что это какой-то фокус. Добавил часть кода, думаю, там всё ясно. Демку делать не буду.

Comment: не фокус, но и не самая очевидная вещь, учитывая количество свойств в контролах и формах, и частоте использования каждого из них. В идеале текстом добавить акцент на использовании конкретного свойства и для чего, хотя бы в комментариях в коде